# -Wundef and -Werror=undef aren't working together in MinGw 4.4.1

Tags: mingw, compiler-warnings

According to the GCC documentation
-Wundef emits a warning when an undefined identifier is used in a #if directive and
-Werror= displays the specified warning as error

But they are not working together in MinGW 4.4.1. Although -Wundef works and -Werror (to display all warnings as error) work.

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds available?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a problem with MinGW 4.4.1
Worked like a charm in 4.6.2