# Generating import library for dbghelp.dll using dlltool of MinGW

Tags: dll, mingw

As mentioned in the first answer to the post 
"[Win32 API stack walk with MinGW/MSYS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318564/win32-api-stack-walk-with-mingw-msys)"
dlltool can be used to generate an import library for MinGW.

But the below command just prints "Create Process" on the screen and generates a 0KB dbghelp.a file

```
dlltool -k -d libdbghelp.def -l dbghelp.a
```

I used the .def file available here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/feature-requests/40/?limit=10&page=1#54a9

The first few lines of the .def file are

```
; File generated automatically from ./dbghelp.spec; do not edit!

LIBRARY dbghelp.dll

EXPORTS
  EnumDirTree@24 @3
  EnumDirTreeW@24 @4
  EnumerateLoadedModules@12 @5
  EnumerateLoadedModules64@12 @6
```

Am I missing something? I am currently using MinGW version 4.4.1

I see that a header file dbghelp.h is also available in the page where I found libdbghelp.def . Where should this be placed?

Also any limitation on the location from where this tool has to be run. I have currently copied the .def file to the same directory as dlltool and executed the command.

Regards,
Shreyas

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with MinGW 4.4.1 again. It works fine if I use 4.6.1.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "again"?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sorry, again was with reference to another post of mine where the problem was again found to be with MinGW 4.4.1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953707/wundef-and-werror-undef-arent-working-together-in-mingw-4-4-1